# How to get the next Non Null value within a group in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sales transaction dataframe which looks as follows:

```
|   id   |  date   |  ammount |last_order_date  |
-------------------------------------------------
|  001   | 2021-01 |    100   |     2020-11     |
|  001   | 2021-02 |      0   |      null       |
|  001   | 2021-03 |      0   |      null       |
|  001   | 2021-04 |     20   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-05 |      0   |      null       |
|  001   | 2021-06 |      0   |      null       |
|  001   | 2021-07 |      0   |      null       |
|  001   | 2021-08 |     50   |     2021-04     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  002   | 2022-03 |      5   |     2022-01     |
|  002   | 2022-04 |     40   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-05 |      0   |      null       |
|  002   | 2022-06 |      0   |      null       |
|  002   | 2022-07 |      0   |      null       |
|  002   | 2022-08 |     35   |     2022-04     |
```

I want to replace the null values in column `last_order_date` by the next non null value of that same column for each group(id) such that I get the dataframe;

```
|   id   |  date   |  ammount |last_order_date  |
-------------------------------------------------
|  001   | 2021-01 |    100   |     2020-11     |
|  001   | 2021-02 |      0   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-03 |      0   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-04 |     20   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-05 |      0   |     2021-04     |
|  001   | 2021-06 |      0   |     2021-04     |
|  001   | 2021-07 |      0   |     2021-04     |
|  001   | 2021-08 |     50   |     2021-04     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  002   | 2022-03 |      5   |     2022-01     |
|  002   | 2022-04 |     40   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-05 |      0   |     2022-04     |
|  002   | 2022-06 |      0   |     2022-04     |
|  002   | 2022-07 |      0   |     2022-04     |
|  002   | 2022-08 |     35   |     2022-04     |
```

For what I have found the method lies on using the last/first function while using a window partitioned by id. However, when I apply the following code;

```
df.withColumn('last_order_date', F.last('last_order_date', ignorenulls = True).over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')))
```

I get the null values replaced by the previous non null value

```
|   id   |  date   |  ammount |last_order_date  |
-------------------------------------------------
|  001   | 2021-01 |    100   |     2020-11     |
|  001   | 2021-02 |      0   |     2020-11     |
|  001   | 2021-03 |      0   |     2020-11     |
|  001   | 2021-04 |     20   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-05 |      0   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-06 |      0   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-07 |      0   |     2021-01     |
|  001   | 2021-08 |     50   |     2021-04     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  002   | 2022-03 |      5   |     2022-01     |
|  002   | 2022-04 |     40   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-05 |      0   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-06 |      0   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-07 |      0   |     2022-03     |
|  002   | 2022-08 |     35   |     2022-04     |
```

I am not quite sure where the problem lies. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can do a self join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're very close. if you use a `first` with your window, but make a sliding window, you can achieve your required result.

```py
import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('last_order_dt_filled', 
               func.first('last_order_dt', ignorenulls=True).
               over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+-------+---+-------------+--------------------+
# | id|     dt|amt|last_order_dt|last_order_dt_filled|
# +---+-------+---+-------------+--------------------+
# |001|2021-01|100|      2020-11|             2020-11|
# |001|2021-02|  0|         null|             2021-01|
# |001|2021-03|  0|         null|             2021-01|
# |001|2021-04| 20|      2021-01|             2021-01|
# |001|2021-05|  0|         null|             2021-04|
# |001|2021-06|  0|         null|             2021-04|
# |001|2021-07|  0|         null|             2021-04|
# |001|2021-08| 50|      2021-04|             2021-04|
# |002|2022-03|  5|      2022-01|             2022-01|
# |002|2022-04| 40|      2022-03|             2022-03|
# |002|2022-05|  0|         null|             2022-04|
# |002|2022-06|  0|         null|             2022-04|
# |002|2022-07|  0|         null|             2022-04|
# |002|2022-08| 35|      2022-04|             2022-04|
# +---+-------+---+-------------+--------------------+
```

The idea is to get the first non-null value starting from the current row to end of the group.